# Fullscreen element when ancestor uses 'transform'

Tags: css, transform

I am trying to create a full-screen image as part of a custom carousel component for a client. I was given a website and have to insert this component into a specific place.
The `vw` and `vh`, as well as using `fixed` and `absolute` position are using the container element as the entire viewport. After much searching, I found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values

`It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport, except when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter property set to something other than none (see the CSS Transforms Spec), in which case that ancestor behaves as the containing block.`

I have found the `transform` attribute being set in 16 separate ancestors (The container I'm working in is a bootstrap-vue tabs component rotated 90 degrees). Is there a way to get around this or override/reset it while I fullscreen the element?

Comment: "a bootstrap-vue tabs component rotated 90 degrees" -- hoo boy... honestly I'd suggest throwing it out and starting over. If that's the level of technical debt you've been given to work with, you'll be spending about 99% of your time just figuring out how that mess even works, leaving almost no time for actual work...

Comment: Is it really that bad? Unfortunately I'm doing it as a remote freelancer, and the website is all but done. I don't think scrapping it is an option.

Comment: It's... pretty bad. In this case, you might be able to work around the problem if you can somehow get the "thing to be made fullscreen" outside of all those `transform` blocks. But other than that... you're going to have trouble.

Comment: Ugh... Yeah, I've already wasted a day and a half on this. Off to the negotiation table I go.